# Can anyone recommend a current, effective captcha solution?

Tags: php, javascript, winforms, captcha, spam

I have a site with a simple form response. A few months ago I started getting  bogus submissions from Russia -- 4 or 5 a day. I have tried several solution to no avail:

1. I added reCaptcha, which worked for a few days, then the spam started again (a quick Google search suggested that reCaptcha had been hacked in 2010!).
2. Next I switched to a simple javascript snippet "What is two plus three?" That too was hacked after a few days.
3. Then I switched to SecureImage (PHP image captcha). Next day, more spam.
4. Then I added a "Title" field to my form and hid it with CSS. My form handler (a php script) rejected the form if the title field was filled in (presumably by a bot). Spammed.
5. Today I modified my javascript to ask different questions. Spammed within the hour.

The logs shows the submissions are coming from different IPs every time. Those with a whois entry are from Russia. Any suggestions how I can deal with this? I'd rather not implement email verification or anything else that might annoy users.

Comment: Maybe someone is simply manually tricking you?

Comment: And you are absolutely sure that the spam comes from that specific form which you're trying to protect?

Comment: @Tom that's a good point. Captchas are made to deter bots (and mildly annoy humans). If the spammer is a determined and/or deranged human who's targeted this site for some reason, then automated solutions aren't going to help.

Comment: It seems unlikely that they'd be human-generated. How can I tell? They're all from different IPs? The logs suggest they are coming from the form page. Is there a way to tell if they're spoofs?

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks this belongs on webmasters?

Answer (score 3):

Captchas are speed bumps, not roadblocks. They will never be a 100% solution.

There are even [web services (with APIs!)](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/security/inside-indias-captcha-solving-economy/1835) that have **humans** solve captchas, for fractions of a cent.

I've also seen a fun implementation where spammers run a "submit this captcha to view the porn gallery" site. They present **your** captcha to the people looking for photos of naked people, and pass their response along to your form.

Comment: I agree, captchas suck. But I have to figure out a way to filter these submissions. The submissions are supposed to be emailed to a fulfillment house, and I don't want the fulfillment guys shipping samples to Russia. One or two a month I can absorb. 4 or 5 a day is too much.

Comment: The simplest solution may be a non-technical one. "Don't ship any to Russia, guys."

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, they are getting better and better each day and there is no sure-fire way of completely stopping SPAM. The best solution is to incorporate a little bit of both. reCAPTCHA is good, but when you combine it with say a mathematical equation, it could do very well. Also, you want to keep in mind not to make SPAM catchers too difficult because they might do well to keep away the spam bots, but they are also good at deterring real users as well.

Also, if you don't want any customer's from Russia, or you know you won't get any real business from anybody other there, then why not just block Russia IP's?

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but how do you block all Russian IPs?

Comment: Yes, I am also curious about how he would go about this. Sounds like it would be a great solution for him.

Comment: Obviously there are ways around it, say if they might be using a proxy, but this site provides a good reference: [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/block-entier-country-using-iptables/)

Comment: Simple google search came up with this: http://www.countryipblocks.net/ There are dozens more. I've searched for "Russia IP range"

Comment: Most web servers offer an option to block by country via the headers as well, so that's always an option, but it's the easiest one to get past as well.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I knew I could block by IP, but not by country. I'll check into that.

Comment: Quick update: I found 2 sources online that let me download lists of Russian IPs for an htaccess deny block. NONE of the Russian IPs from my server logs were on the downloaded lists :( Not very encouraging.

Comment: Well, you said Russia, but how sure are you that they are actually from Russia? Try blocking any non-North American countries.

Comment: Hmm, that might work. It makes me nervous though, since IPs are being added daily. It would probably require constant maintenance to keep current. Maybe I could point non-North American IPs to an alternate form, which DOES require email verification - just so someone doesn't accidently fall through the cracks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to boast because it'll be hacked tonight if I link to it, but I made one that seems to work quite well. In essence (and I'll let you work out the details for yourself) I have a dozen simple photos - cat, dog, car, plane, bird etc. - and I show them alongside a form field with a randomised name (something like MD5( rand(1,10000) ) ). To complete the form the user has to write dog or cat or whatever in the text field.

Comment: So a botmaster only needs to visit your site multiple times, download all the images and label them manually once, then his bots can compare to his already written database against his images, and write correct values each time.

Comment: The proof of the pudding's in the eating. It's worked for a couple of years while everything else I've tried has failed. Most of my clients don't want this method because they don't want the silly little pictures of cats and dogs. The hack you suggest might not work because of the form field having a different name every time. I'm not going to fight it out with you - it's just a suggestion.

Comment: A captcha solution working for a long time isn't necessarily an indication that it's a good captcha. It could just be that you don't get enough traffic to write a custom solution for.

Comment: The different name will not deter bots from filling it, they can and will read the direct HTML source EVERY TIME, the name doesn't matter for them. Maybe if you had several such fields, all with random and changing names, with their order scrambled (with JavaScript, also done randomly) and all of them are hidden except for one, it might confuse the bot about which one to fill out (because if all of them are field the PHP should reject it).

Comment: You're right. And the spam comes in spates. Sometimes you get thousands a day and then you get none for months. No solution is perfect, that's certain. Changing the name of fields does help - making some fields blank (i.e. bin the response if this field is filled) also seems to help.

Comment: Crossed in the post there. An interesting discussion though.

Answer (score 0):

I came across NuCaptcha on Slashdot, it uses video instead of pictures to make it much harder for the bots to read but easy for you and I as it does not have to be crazy scrambled. its works very well so far but i agree with ceejayoz. If anything, just to kick the tires and see what you think of it.

```
http://www.nucaptcha.com/
```

Comment: This is not an effective solution considering it uses Flash. If they converted to canvas/HTMl5 elements, it might be better.

Comment: @NickGeorge I didn't realize it used flash, i agree with you 100%

Comment: @NickGeorge and Drewedin: The problem is that although HTML5 is preferable long-term, there are an awful lot of users out there whose browsers don't support it. Much as I hate Flash, it's still got a huge install base so it is a viable option. Of course, the ideal is HTML5 with a fallback to Flash...

Comment: @Basic, but the same can be said with Flash. An ever growing support for non-flash applications is needed with the mobile market booming.

Comment: @NickGeorge Let's sidestep the issue of flash on mobile devices 'cos it always results in arguments :) Frankly, I wish everyone would hurry up and upgrade - I only managed to drop support for IE6 about 6 months ago (Public sector clients)